# What are the applications of Weierstrass function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

Differentiability is an appreciated characteristics in analysis, a feature that does not exist in the realm of [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function). I am curious about the applications of this function related to not only the development of other mathematical concepts but also modeling purposes in engineering. Wikipedia only cites one application

> ... practical applications such as models of Brownian motion
> necessitated infinitely jagged functions (nowadays known as fractal
> curves).

Can one name more applications?

Answer (score 2):

That Wikipedia paragraph is not discussing the applications of the Weierstrass function specifically, beyond serving as a counterexample. It is saying that functions that are continuous everywhere but differentiable nowhere can have practical applications, such as modeling the physical phenomenon known as [Brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion).

The first couple paragraphs on the [Wiener proces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process) might be interesting to you. Finance (e.g. Black-Scholes; modeling stock prices using such a function) is just one example.